# ruby on rails costum show/index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so basically i have this:

```
create_table "notifs", force: true do |t|
      t.string   "desc"
      t.string   "sender"
      t.string   "receiver"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Autogenerated by scaffold method, but now i want to have a get method that displays all data(default-Working), and more 1 for searching by sender, like notifs?sender=name or something else

I tried already changing the Index method to:

```
def index
    if params[:sender].present?
      @notifs = Notif.find_by_sender(params[:sender]);
    else
      @notifs = Notif.all
    end
end
```

but the result is

```
undefined method `each' for #<Notif:0x38c6e98>
-------
app/views/notifs/index.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_notifs_index_html_erb__382580733_32546088'
```

I even tried creating a new route

```
get '/searchsender' => 'notifs#searchsender'
--------
# get /searchsender
# get /searchsender
def searchsender
    @notifs = Notif.find_by_sender("asd") #"asd" hardcoded, just for testing
  if !@notifs
    render :json=>{:notif=>"not working"}
  else
    render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @notifs  
  end  
end
```

but the result is

```
undefined method `desc' for nil:NilClass
-------
app/views/notifs/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_notifs_show_html_erb__30604837_29852568'
app/controllers/notifs_controller.rb:91:in `searchsender'
```

Despite I have 2 different methods, i prefer the easy/fastest way...
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_all_by` instead of `find_by`. The former returns an array of records that match the condition, latter returns the first record that matches the condition. So in the view when `each` was called on a single object it gave the error: `undefined method each for #<Notif:0x38c6e98>`.

```
def index
    if params[:sender].present?
      @notifs = Notif.find_all_by_sender(params[:sender]);
    else
      @notifs = Notif.all
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much... i'm admired how the answer is so simple and still so hard to find